# Unable to click on SwitchPreference with Espresso Ui Test (Android)

Tags: android-espresso-web

I am having one **SwitchPreference** (PreferenceFragmentCompat) and wanted to click on the toggle button. But I am unable to do so.

Here’s my code:

```
@Test
fun settings_testSwitch() {
    pressAudioOnlyToggle()
}
```

```
fun pressAudioOnlyToggle() {
    onData(allOf(`is`(instanceOf(Preference::class.java)), withText(“Audio only"))).perform(click())
}
```

I am getting one error like the following:

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using **PreferenceFragmentCompat**, so you need to pass **recycler_view** as the id, because **PreferenceFragmentCompat** uses a **RecyclerView** internally. And then you need to use **RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem**.

Let’s look at the code below:

```
fun pressAudioOnlyToggle() {
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(androidx.preference.R.id.recycler_view))
    .perform(
        RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
            ViewMatchers.hasDescendant(ViewMatchers.withText("Audio only")),
            ViewActions.click()
        )
    )
}
```

This will press on the switch and turn it on (if it was off previously).

Comment: This makes total sense to me. Thanks a lot man. @Sayan